# "Research" tag: define usage guidance or remove?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I know that this has been brought up before (see some previous questions at the bottom of this post), but as far as I can tell there has not been a question devoted specifically to this tag. It would be good to get some sort of consensus.

There are currently <s>102</s> <s>52</s> **0** questions tagged [research](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research), with seemingly nothing in common except that they are about people researching their genealogy. Which kind of defeats the purpose of a tag.

The tag usage guidance is currently no guidance at all:

> The study of source materials to establish facts and reach
>   conclusions.

**Should the [research](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) tag even exist? If it should, what should the usage guidance be?**

---

<sub>***Previous mentions:***

15 Jul 2015: [Should we blacklist some tags that can be applied to almost every question?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2059/should-we-blacklist-some-tags-that-can-be-applied-to-almost-every-question)

11 Oct 2012: [Proposal to remove tags like brick-wall and road-block](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81/proposal-to-remove-tags-like-brick-wall-and-road-block)

10 Oct 2012: [What is the difference between the [research] and [research-methods] tags?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38/what-is-the-difference-between-the-research-and-research-methods-tags)</sub>

Comment: I and others are in the process of burninating the [tag:research] tag.

Comment: @PolyGeo What better way to spend a Saturday than retagging [tag:research] questions - so I finished it up today, except there's still one merged question that I can't edit

Comment: Thanks for doing that @HarryVervet.  My mod powers let me do that last one.

Comment: Nice to see a plan come to fruition :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **Remove the [research](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) tag.**

I have never tagged any of my questions [research](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) even though most are about research.

There is nothing in common with questions tagged [research](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research), rendering the tag useless. For questions about specific aspects of research we have the following tags:

- [research-methods](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-methods): For questions about how to conduct genealogy research and best practices for genealogy research.
- [research-travel](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-travel): To be used for questions about planning for, conducting and recording travel trips in the pursuit of genealogical research.
- [research-guides](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-guides)
- [locating-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/locating-records): Questions about locating specific records of reference works identified by geography, date, type or topic. Used to enquire about availability and identification of such resources.

Answer (score 1):

For the tags listed --

- [research-methods](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-methods): For questions about how to conduct genealogy research and best practices for genealogy research.

In [What is the difference between the [research] and [research-methods] tags?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38/what-is-the-difference-between-the-research-and-research-methods-tags), there was a suggestion about whether the tag should be [research-methods](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-methods) or [methodology](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/methodology).  I'm leaning towards [research-methods](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-methods).

- [research-guides](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-guides): Suggest adding something like this: "For questions about finding 'how-to' articles about specific record types and information papers about specific record groups"

Comment: When a tag like [tag:research-guides] has no wiki, I think it may be best to simply give it one rather than proposing it in an answer.  At the moment there is no [tag:methodology] tag so I think we should leave it that way, or make a synonym that points it at [tag:research-methods].